# Using classList on a node collection

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the error I get using `.classList.contains()`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

and please explain why it does not work: I need it for my apprenticeship

```
<div class="game-grid">
        <button class="covered" <?php print $array[0]?>></button>
        <button class="covered" <?php print $array[1]?>></button>
        <button class="covered" <?php print $array[2]?>></button>
        <button class="covered" <?php print $array[3]?>></button>
        <button class="covered" <?php print $array[4]?>></button>
        <button class="covered" <?php print $array[5]?>></button>
        <button class="covered" <?php print $array[6]?>></button>
        <button class="covered" <?php print $array[7]?>></button>
        <button class="covered" <?php print $array[8]?>></button>
        <button class="covered" <?php print $array[9]?>></button>
    </div>
    <script>



        let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("covered");

        if(buttons.classList.contains("choosen") == false){

            for (button of buttons) {
                button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
                    event.target.classList.add("choosen");
                    event.target.classList.remove("covered");
                });
            }

        }     

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a node collection, so you need to loop over that collection and check the *n-th* element `.classList`